# ASP.NET Ajax vs. JQuery for web service calls

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am dipping my feet into an app that uses both ASP.NET Ajax (ControlToolkit, etc.) as well as Jquery.

Are there any pros/cons to using the ASP.NET Ajax mechanics for calling JSON-serialized .NET web service methods ... vs. using JQuery .ajax()? (Or is it "6 and 1/2 dozen"?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Ajax is deprecated and, I believe, no longer supported. It is pretty bulky too, as it tries to generate JavaScript objects instead of just using JSON. `$.ajax` is strongly recommended instead.

[Here is a blog post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx) that discusses the situation. It turns out ASP.NET Ajax is being moved into the Ajax Control Toolkit, which itself is shifting to a server-control focus. So if you're using ASP.NET WebForms and all the `<asp:Whatever />` controls, Ajax Control Toolkit is OK... otherwise, e.g. if you're using ASP.NET MVC, definitely stick with jQuery.